# Seperate Digits of Positive Integer in JS using while loop without string/array

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop, numbers, digits

I am trying to run a program that, upon receiving a positive integer, splits it into its separate digits like so. Number is 652, output is 2, 5, 6. There is supposed to no arrays and I can't make the number a string. I've written most of the code but it's missing something that I can't figure out. The issue is really that I don't know how to store the numbers to be output during iterations. Would appreciate any help. I am using a while loop but for loop could be used as well.

```
function problem_09() {

  var outputObj=document.getElementById("output");

  var a = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number: ", ""));
  var i = 0;
  var digits = ;

  outputObj.innerHTML="number: "+a+"<br><br>its digits: ";

  while (a>0) {
    digits[i]= a%10;

    a = Math.floor(a/10);
    i++;
  }

  outputObj.innerHTML=digits;

  outputObj.innerHTML=outputObj.innerHTML+"<br><br>"+"program ended";
  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("disabled","true");
}
```

I know the issue lies with the digits and the i but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You have syntax errors, for example: `var digits = ;`

Comment: @Naruto Abidal you want an algorithm which covert `652` to `[2,5,6]`?

Comment: Yes, I know the syntax error. I just don't know what to put there. And I want it to simply output 2, 5, 6 for example but it should run for any positive integer

Answer (score 1):

You could take a place value and multiply by 10 for each iteration.

```js
function getDigits(value) {
    var place = 1;

    while (value >= place) {
        console.log(Math.floor(value / place) % 10);
        place *= 10;
    }
}

getDigits(652);
getDigits(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without using `Math.floor(...)`

```js
function getDigits(n) {
  var res = [];

  while (n > 0) {
    var r = n % 10,
      d = n - r,
      curr = d / 10;
    n = curr;
    res.push(r);
  }

  return res;
}

var n = prompt("Enter a number: "),
  output = document.getElementById("output");
output.textContent = getDigits(+n);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

then just to replace

```
var i = 0;
var digits = [];

while (a > 0) {
    digits.push(a % 10);
    a = Math.floor(a/10);
    i++;
}
```

the question does not make really sense.. without arrays, but he is actually expecting the result to be an array...